# Loopback DENY In Acl Is Not working

Tags: acl, strongloop, loopback

I'm new to loopback. I have created ACL for Deny permission for all users($everyone).But I could access all API through swagger.Can anyone explain this?
Following is My ACL. Thanks.

```
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Possible reason:

To [enable access control](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Controlling+data+access), you must call `enableAuth()`. For example, in a boot script `server/boot/authentication.js`:

```
module.exports = function enableAuthentication(server) {
  server.enableAuth();
};
```

Also check your `server/model-config.json` file to see if your `ACL`, `RoleMapping` and `Role` models are linked correctly to your datasource.

Your ACL is correct, so a problem is somewhere else. In case my answer doesn't help you, you might want to clone [loopback-example-access-control repository](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control), try if it works for you and eventually try to figure out, how it differs from your solution.

You can also try to [debug](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Controlling+data+access#Controllingdataaccess-Debugging) it by specyfing a `DEBUG` environment variable with value `loopback:security:*` for the console to log the lookups and checks the server makes as requests come in.

Comment: Why the downvote? If someone can add a reason for a downvote into a comment, I can update my answer to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `accessType` like this:

```
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY"
}
```

Otherwise, the best thing to do is to clone the [LoopBack-sandbox](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sandbox) and reproduce the issue in that repository and post an issue on GitHub.

Comment: @richardpringle.Thanks for the response.But still it is not working

Comment: Note that according to LoopBack's [guidelines](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/wiki/Questions), they do not appreciate posting questions as GitHub issues. Use [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/loopbackjs) or [gitter](https://gitter.im/strongloop/loopback) instead.

Comment: @Riyash.D, if you fork the [loopback-sandbox](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sanbox) and reproduce your issue in the fork, you can comment on here and someone can go and take a look and tell you exactly what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `accessType` field value to `EXECUTE` from `*`.

Answer (score 0):

It also depending on your base model, as it might get overwritten by the base model's ACL.

For example, if your model is a `User` base model, the `"create"` method will still work even if you put `DENY` to `$everyone`, unless you specify `"property": ["create"]`.

```
"acls": [
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY",
      "property": [
        "create"
      ]
    }
]
```

Reference (List of User base ACLs): https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/user.json